# Change Media volume in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

Can I change  the media volume? and how? I used this so far:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

But have a seekbar and want to change the media volume, not ring volume.

So can someone show me how to just change the media volume at `onCreate()` and I fix the seekbar later.

Comment: I use this method too. 
For some reason i am not able to call:-
context.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) from my surface view? i cant replace "context" with "this" since im not in an Activity.. any hints?

Comment: I want to silent only ringer on incoming call not playing video .How I can solve this ,I am having issue with xiaomi mobile...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The right method to use would be [setStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume) on your `AudioManager`. It could looks like this

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
    (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                             [int value],
                             [if desired a flag]);
```

An example use of the flag is to get the beep when setting the volume so the user can hear the outcome. The flag for that would be `AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND`.

You could use `AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI` if you don't want to play a sound but display a toast with the current value. The use has to get a feedback tho. Doesn't matter if it is audible or visual.

To get the maximal valid value for the given stream you just call `getStreamMaxVolume()` on the `AudioManager` and get an integer back which represents ... well the maximal valid value for the volume.

Comment: 1. i dont want any sound and i get a error if i remove the flag.

Comment: 2. What is the possible value where you typed [int value] ?
sorry i accedentally pressed enter and thought i just jump one row instead of posting.

Comment: does this need any permission?

Comment: Hey, I was trying to create a mute and un-mute button in my app. I want the unmute to set to the volume of the users volume before entering the app. I tried to use your explanation, but ran into an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589116/the-audio-volume-is-zero?noredirect=1#comment54954950_33589116

Comment: @wutzebaer No. But there is a permission called "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" , which is a bit odd...

Answer (score 40):

```
private AudioManager audio;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Override onKeyDown:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    default:
        // return false;
        // Update based on @Rene comment below:
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, but the default should be: return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); Else you lose the back key to end the app e.g.

Comment: Very true... I probably caught that too but excluded it for the example and then kept false in there because of scrolling issues with the trackball.

Comment: Note that the documentation for `adjustStreamVolume` and other methods says *"This method should only be used by applications that replace the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application."* https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: @trgraglia: Is there any special API call required to set volume of external headset connected through my audio slot?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following code to handle Volume using a SeekBar:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

SeekBar sbVolumeBooster = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbVolumeBooster);
sbVolumeBooster.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)); 
sbVolumeBooster.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));  

sbVolumeBooster.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
    {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                progress, 0);  // 0 can also be changed to AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the actual acceptable answer for programmatically sound change.

Answer (score 5):

Giving a 0 - in the flags avoids getting a visual and audio indicator .
That's good when you implement your own audio bar and indicator and you don't want android to add anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use `adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, flags);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume(int, int, int)

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, but this is the list of possible flags: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES You could also try giving it a number like 0 that isn't used for any of the flags. This might indicate not using any flag.

Comment: 0 would imply no flags.