# Android: Show Media Volume Slider on the UI

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**UPDATE:**

so i am using `seekbar` and Seekbar and hook up the listeners

onCreate method:

```
audio = (AudioManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
volume_label.setText(String.valueOf(volume));*/ 
volumebar.setMax(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)); 
volumebar.setProgress(60); 
volumebar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(VolumeChange); 

this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


private OnSeekBarChangeListener VolumeChange = new  OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    { 
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        { 
            int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
             audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, index, 1); 
           //  volume_label.setText(String.valueOf(index)); 
        } 
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {
            //
        } 

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {
            //
        } 
    };
```

but i can use the seeker but does not effect the audio sound, try to increase and decrease the sound but no effect, what else should i be implementing?

**UPDATE END**

I am working on a MediaPlayer which has play/pause/prev/next/seeker everything works as expected and I am planning to add `volume slider` so user can change the volume instead of using hardware volume up/down buttons.

i tried this code but did not show-up on the UI like.

Inside onCreate Method:

```
Activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)  

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 40, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178989/android-development-change-media-volume

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope this helps other... here is how i able to achieved:

```
  leftAm = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = leftAm.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = leftAm.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.leftVolume);
    volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
    volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     leftAm.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
    }
   });
```

.xml:

```
<SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/volumebar"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
```