# Android tutorial Button "Save" the changes in Ringtone, Notification Volume

Tags: android, button, savechanges, savestate

Doese anyone know of a tutorial on how to make a Volume Controller like [this one](http://picz.ro/index.php?id=63acd2fead2cd8a8dd6e5d29a6350d53) (with a Save button at the bottom). This is my problem, how to make that "Save" button. I can create all the volume SeekBars, but unfortunately when I make changes on SseekBar it automatically changes the volume from the phone settings (ringer, notification, media, in call).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what volume do you want to change and save? If it already changes the volumes, why do you want to save it?

Comment: @slybloty I want to have a Panel with all Volumes from Phone (Just like in Sound Settings from an ANdroid Phone) with "OK" and "Cancel" Button. I don't want acctualy, when i move the seekBar to change instantly the volume. First move the seekBar, then press "Save" to save the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use the `SeekBar` and retrieve the value it sets to. Don't set the volumes while the `SeekBar` is adjusted. And then, when the button **Save** is pushed, send those values to the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Use this link for more detailed explanation: [Android Development: Change Media volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4179507/935627) as well as this one: [SeekBar1.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/SeekBar1.html)

Here's a quick example of how it might look like:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

ImageButton save = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.save);

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, valueFromSeekBar, flagIfNeeded);
    }
}); //End setOnClickListener()
```

Comment: Thanks for the search mate, but how can i send those valuse to AudioManager when **Save** is pushe? i mean in `save.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener){ // code}` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I've improved my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate. Now i have an ideea how could work. At first runtime, my apps get crash, but i'll figure it out .