# The audio volume is zero?

Tags: java, android, xml, optimization, android-manifest

I have an application with a mute button. I have been stuck on this for 4 and a half hours now, so I am plain desperate. I am trying to have the volume mute when user clicks **mute** and unmute when user clicks it again. This works fine, except the audio isn't playing. For some reason, Stream_Music is 0?

```
 public void mute(View view) {
        mutebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mutebutton);

        if ((variableForMute.x % 2) != 0) { //If it's odd UNMUTE
            Log.v(TAG, "Use this volume to unmute " +userVolumeOnStart.userVolume +"");
            Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "UNMUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.userVolume, 0);
            variableForMute.x++;


        } else { //If its even MUTE
            userVolumeOnStart.userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            Log.v(TAG, "Right Before Mute " +userVolumeOnStart.userVolume +"");
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
            Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            variableForMute.x++;
        }
    }
```

Here is the beginning where I declare the variables and objects:

```
ImageButton leftcenter;
ImageButton mutebutton;
final String TAG = "userVolume";
private AudioManager mAudioManager;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__menu);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    leftcenter = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startGame);


}
```

The thing is, as log outputs, I am getting the following:

[image]

I should have the volume change to what my volume was before I started my app. I want to be able to have the user unmute the app to the same volume that the user was originally on. But for some reason it is always 0!? Why is this happening? My phone volume is at full?!

Please help,

I have spent way too much time on this-I appreciate all feedback:
 positive, negative, neutral, whatever.

Comment: there are several volumes on android. It is possible that you think the volume is at full, but only the ring volume is at that level, and the music is mute.

Comment: @njzk2 How should I unMute the music volume then?

Comment: set it to a value that is not 0?

Comment: @njzk2 It isn't set to 0...Where do you see that?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, and that was the issue. I managed to fix that by changing from STREAM_MUSIC to STREAM_RING. For some reason, the audio isn't playing now? The logs are working now, when I change the volume. But the audio just isn't playing in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I have changed `STRAM_MUSIC` to `STREAM_RING`, and the variable `userVolumeOnStart.userVolume` changes successfully!

Answer (score 0):

btn_mute.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if(isChecked) {
                btn_mute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mute_bt);
                audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
            } else {
                btn_mute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_bt);
                audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
            }
        }
    });
```