# Sound not working? ( still needs an answer )

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, service

My audio isn't playing...I've been stuck on this for around 7 hours (ALL DAY!), and have cannot figure out the issue.  I am trying to have the volume mute when user clicks mute and unmute when user clicks it again.

I want to be able to have the user unmute the app to the same volume that the user was originally on. `userVolumeOnStart.userVolume` is where the users original volume is stored in. I use this value in the unMute, to set their volume to what it used to be.

For example:

**If your volume was 7 and you used my mute button:**

**Open app->Mute (Volume=0)->Unmute(Volume = 7 again) etc.**

Here is the listener to the mute button:

```
 public void mute(View view) {
        mutebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mutebutton);

        if ((variableForMute.x % 2) != 0) { //If it's odd UNMUTE
            Log.v(TAG, "Use this volume to unmute " +userVolumeOnStart.userVolume +"");
            Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "UNMUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, userVolumeOnStart.userVolume, 0);
            variableForMute.x++;


        } else { //If its even MUTE
            userVolumeOnStart.userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            Log.v(TAG, "Right Before Mute " +userVolumeOnStart.userVolume +"");
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
            Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            variableForMute.x++;
        }
    }
```

userVolumeOnStart.userVolume is a variable that I defined in a seperate class, to use it globally. Here is where the audio actually runs. I can assure you the issue is not here (as I have not messed with the code in this class today) , but I will still provide the code anyway:

```
     cdt = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Log.v(TAG, millisUntilFinished + "left");

            millisUntilFinishedRounded = ((500 + millisUntilFinished) / 1000) * 1000;

            if (millisUntilFinishedRounded == 10000) { //TEN SECONDS


                    ten = MediaPlayer.create(TwentySeconds.this, R.raw.tenmoreseconds);
                ten.start();

            }

            if (millisUntilFinishedRounded == 3000) {

                three = MediaPlayer.create(TwentySeconds.this, R.raw.threetwoone);
                three.start();
            }
        }
```

This is a service that runs in the background when the app starts.

Here is my log after changing ringer volume on my phone while app is running and pressing the mute button. It shows that userVolumeOnStart.userVolume is doing what it's supposed to be doing:

[image]

I am desperate now, so I would really appreciate **any** feedback (negative or positive!)

Thanks so much,

```
{Rich}
```

**By the way, my question is not a duplicate of [The audio volume is zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589116/the-audio-volume-is-zero).** I have changed the audio stream since that question, and have figured out the problem there. There, there was an issue with `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` where `userVolumeOnStart.userVolume` would always be 0. I have changed STRAM_MUSIC to STREAM_RING. That is not the issue now, as `userVolumeOnStart.userVolume` **successfully** changes based on user volume. The problem **now** is that the Media Players are not effectively working for an unknown reason.

Comment: "My audio isn't playing..." - You aren't getting any sound at all?

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, thats whats weird! Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: You may be new to SO, but please stop posting the same question [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589665/audio-not-playing) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589116/the-audio-volume-is-zero) - if people can help you, they will. Also, don't add a signature to the bottom of your questions - it will get edited out and you are not helping yourself. Stick to the question, post it **once** and give people time to help you.

Comment: @adelphus **By the way, my question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589116/the-audio-volume-is-zero.** I have changed the audio stream since that question, and have figured out the problem there. There, there was an issue with `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` where `userVolumeOnStart.userVolume` would always be 0. I have changed STRAM_MUSIC to STREAM_RING. That is not the issue now, as `userVolumeOnStart.userVolume` **successfully** changes based on user volume. The problem **now** is that the Media Players are not effectively working for an unknown reason.

Comment: @MikeM. Also, I know that userVolumeOnStart.userVolume is a working int. For some reason, when I plug userVolumeOnStart.userVolume back into the unMute option, the audio doesn't play...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after 2 days!

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.MYAUDIO);
```

**I shouldn't break it up into declaration and instantiation:**

Mp.create will call the static method which is an instance that won't get stored. When I call start() I am starting the original MediaPlayer, not the instance! So basically, I am satrting something that I never even stored, and that's why the audio wasn't playing!