# setVolumeControlStream doesn't work

Tags: android, controls, volume

I'm trying to change the volume control in my app. So I found out that I have to use the `"setVolumeControlStream"` function in the onCreate method. Now I have a fragment and its not changing anything. Some ideas to get this method work?

What I tried: `getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`

Comment: are using it in the onCreate method of your fragment?

Comment: You should as well refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178989/change-media-volume-in-android

Comment: Im not talking about changing the volume I want to change the Control Stream so If the user wants to make the volume lower it changes the media volume and not the ring tone

Comment: yes I am Nolly J. onCreateView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [setVolumeControlStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29) says:

> The suggested audio stream will be tied to the window of this Activity.

So if you are creating a SurfaceView to play video, for example, then the SurfaceView has its own window separate from the Activity's window. The volume control setting on the Activity wouldn't affect the SurfaceView window which may have focus.