# Raise volume progressively in Android app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I've got an app where Ii want to sound the alarm ringtone and raise the volume each second.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
```

After initializing AudioManager and MediaPlayer, I've got a method which is executed each second when some circumstances occur. The method is the next one:

```
private void sound() {
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        try {
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(5,5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.start();
    } else {
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,0);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first time the method is executed the sound begins, that works OK. But when is already started and I want to raise the volume, the adjustStreamVolume makes nothing.

Any help or advice?

Comment: start a thread when player is playing and in that increase player volume and provide sleep time =1 sec

Comment: Vivek, the problem is not the execution each second, the problem is that it's not changing the volume.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178989/change-media-volume-in-android