# Change the volume programmatically in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to change the volume of device ? I use **react-native-audio-streaming** to load external files from network and I need to change the volume using my slider.

Comment: `react-native-audio-streaming` seems to just be a pretty basic wrapper around native modules for android and ios. To control the media volume, you would have to extend the component to allow you access to the volume of the media. [Here's how to do it in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no) and [Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178989/change-media-volume-in-android). you should be able to take the solutions outlined in those posts to extend the react-native-audio-streaming

Comment: See [How to get the volume level information in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217739/how-to-get-the-volume-level-information-in-react-native/61738461) for details.