# How to get the volume level information in React Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to get the event of device's mute/increase/decrease sound event in React native.

Comment: Use this library for it. https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ans. Without using Library is it possible?

Comment: You have integrate module for it. which is inside the library.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for your kind help. That solved my issue. @KiritModi brother.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [react-native-system-setting](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting) library to set the volume.

```
import SystemSetting from 'react-native-system-setting'

...

SystemSetting.setVolume(0.5);
```

You can also get the current volume:

```
SystemSetting.getVolume().then(currentVolume => console.log(currentVolume));
```

Or listen to changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const volumeListener = SystemSetting.addVolumeListener(data => {
        console.log(data.volume);
    });

    return () => SystemSetting.removeVolumeListener(volumeListener)  
}, [])
```

Thanks @Kirit-Modi, for his comment.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, no events are raised.

Comment: @Chaki_Black Please open an issue in the repo of the lib.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hirbod/react-native-volume-manager

This one works

```
import { VolumeManager } from 'react-native-volume-manager';

// Enable or disable the native volume toast globally (iOS, Android)
VolumeManager.showNativeVolumeUI({ enabled: true }); // default is true

// Set the volume (value between 0 and 1)
await VolumeManager.setVolume(0.5); // float value between 0 and 1

// Set volume with additional options
await VolumeManager.setVolume(0.5, {
  type: 'system', // default: "music" (Android only)
  showUI: true, // default: false (suppress native UI volume toast for iOS & Android)
  playSound: false, // default: false (Android only)
});

// Get the current volume async (type defaults to "music")
const { volume } = await VolumeManager.getVolume({ type: 'music' });

// Listen to volume changes (example)
useEffect(() => {
  const volumeListener = VolumeManager.addVolumeListener((result) => {
    console.log(result.volume); // current volume as a float (0-1)

    // On Android, the result object also has the keys:
    // music, system, ring, alarm, notification
  });

  // Clean up function
  return () => {
    volumeListener.remove(); // remove listener
  };
}, []);
```