# How to detect press volume buttons in IOS ReactNative

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am doing iOS react-native app. App is video player, which can connect to ChromeCast. I have a task to control ChromeCast volume with iPhone volume buttons. Does anyone know how to do it in react-native. Or at least explain how to detect it with IOS (objective-c)?

Regards,
Vitalii

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect volume button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/detect-volume-button-press)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61738461/19027584

Answer (score 0):

Using this library https://github.com/rtmalone/react-native-volume-control you can detect volume press event via hardware button

Comment: That looks very promising but it's not been touched in years and needs a bit of attention before it can be used again.

Comment: @JulianH You can always fork the repo and make necessary and add your github link as npm module or publish to npm as your own module. I am gonna try doing that.

Comment: If you do make changes I'd love to use them!