# Allow Android users to change media volume by default in React Native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm making an Android-only React Native app displaying audio.

I want users to be able to change their media volume while in the app instead of the default ringtone volume when pressing hardware buttons.

Is this possible using React Native only or do I have to bridge some native module, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178989/change-media-volume-in-android) ?

Comment: You would need a native module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by adding this Android code to the `MainActivity.java` in my native Android code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

This makes the whole app use the media volume slider by default when pressing hardware volume buttons.

Comment: Need to import AudioManager from `import android.media.AudioManager;`

Comment: didn't work for me. are there any other options?